# Allow always downloads for m3u8 file selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

In a selenium & python script I need to download always automatically without the popup that appears to confirm when I download .m3u8 files.

I tried the following code but it is not working even if I set to download always for any file, what should I change in those options?

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import os

firefoxOptions = Options()
firefoxOptions.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
firefoxOptions.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
firefoxOptions.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.getcwd())
firefoxOptions.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", True)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefoxOptions)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting this preference it is working

```
firefoxOptions.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl")
```